# SyntaxError in rails app controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I used the twitter bootstrap library for my new simple rails app
and used some scaffold for products model
i updated the GemFile as well as the bundle command and the rails g bootstrap.
when i run the web page i get the following error:

```
SyntaxError in ProductsController#index

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.4/app/helpers/glyph_helper.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected ':'
...   content_tag :i, nil, class: names.map{|name| "icon-#{name...
```

I don't know why this happened!

Here is my GemFile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.7'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'json'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

controller code:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @products }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @product }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/new
  # GET /products/new.json
  def new
    @product = Product.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @product }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, :notice => 'Product was successfully created.' }  
        format.json { render :json => @product, :status => :created, :location => @product }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /products/1
  # PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
        format.html { redirect_to @product, :notice => 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually your error comes from `content_tag :i, nil, class: names.map{|name| "icon-#{name` and it's not in your controller

Comment: and what ruby version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 what is the solution for this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution seems simple. I guess the version of some gem you are using requires ruby version > 1.9.0 because of the symbol feature so you can do `bar: foo` instead of `:bar => foo`

So if you change to ruby 1.9.2 or 1.9.2 that issue will go away!